# Storing the data of a card by using onDismissed

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to save the data on a card after it is dismissed?

I am trying to figure out a way that when the user dismiss the card by swiping it, the content of this card would be stored somewhere on my database so that I can use this information later.

I am not sure if I can pass any arguemnt to onDismissed though to store the objects.

The logic I am trying to develop is as follows

```
....
cardInfo.map(
                      (Info info) =>
                  new Dismissible(
                      direction: DismissDirection.horizontal ,
                      onDismissed: _store( ,info),
                      child : new Card(
                    child: new ListTile(
    ...

//Jump to _store

 _store(DismissDirection direction, Info info) {

    // TODO storing object data 

  }
```

So basically what I am trying to do is to link between my current processed info object and the function that is called when the card of this object is dismissed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you create your ListTiles depending on the info-object.

onDismissed has just the dismiss direction as an argument, but no one restricts you from calling a method which takes the info object as well:

```
onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) => _store(direction, info)
...
void _store(direction, info) {
  //Make a call to your backend storing the info object
  http.post(url, info);
}
```

But you essentially have listed all that in you question. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes this should work, my mistake is that I was trying to call the function directly with onDismissed, and pass to it the info object. I could not have figured out calling my function inside the callback for dismissed without your help. Thank you very much.